# Capturar vários endereços de links com RegEx no PHP

Tags: php, regex

Estou utilizando a função `file_get_contents()` em uma página que retorna vários endereços de links no corpo:

```
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-logo="http://www.brandemia.org/sites/default/files/sites/default/files/axn_logo_antiguo.jpg" group-title="Cine",AXN (MX)
http://live.izzitv.mx/Content/HLS/Live/Channel(AXN)/index.key

#EXTINF:-1 tvg-logo="https://i.imgur.com/Wrgs4X2.png" group-title="Cine",AMC (MX)
http://live.izzitv.mx/Content/HLS/Live/Channel(AMC_HD)/index.key
```

Queria utilizar a função `preg_match_all()` para procurar os endereços, especificamente os terminados com a palavra `key`.

PS.:Os endereços podem começar com *http* ou também com *https*.

Exemplo: `http://live.izzitv.mx/Content/HLS/Live/Channel(AXN)/index.key`

Mas todas as minhas tentativas foram drásticas, não consegui chegar nem perto do resultado esperado...

Comment: Você já tentou de alguma forma? Só a expressão regular é suficiente pra sanar sua dúvida?

Comment: olha pesquisei sim sobre expressão regular, porem nao consegui de jeito nenhum fazer algo que funcionasse

Comment: Então. A expressão regular é bem útil quando o tal conteúdo da página segue um padrão... Aliás, não é difícil fazer... Uma resposta baseando-se no link da pergunta te resolve?

Comment: Sim, toda ajuda é bem vinda

Comment: É necessário utilizaar `file_get_contents` + `preg_match_all`?? Caso seja, dê mais detalhes: Os links estão nos elementos `<a>`? Possui alguma classe de identificação? Tem algum trecho do HTML do site que estás utilizando para extração? Qual o seu código? Caso não seja necessário o uso das funções supramencionadas, eu recomendo utilizar `DOMDocument` + `DOMXPath`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "*- [...] uma pagina com diversos tipos de links [...]*".

Como você disse que é uma página com diversos links, presumo(imos) que estes links são um elemento `a` com atributo `href` e tal...

Como mencionei no comentário, para utilizar a expressão regular o ideal é que os links sigam um padrão. No caso desses links estarem em uma página, fiz esta expressão regular delimitando o link pelas aspas que, normalmente, delimitam o atributo `href`, que é onde fica o endereço do link (e bla bla bla):

```
\"((http|https)\:\/\/([^\"]+)\.key)\"
```

Teste no [RegEx101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Puk6jD/1):

[image: Print do RegEx101.com]

Agora basta capturar o grupo `$1` no seu script:

```
<?php

$conteudo_da_pagina = '<a href="http://site.com/palavra.key"></a>
<a href="https://site.com/palavra.key"></a>
<a href="http://subdominio.site.com/palavra.key"></a>
<a href="https://subdominio.site.com/palavra.chave"></a>
<a href="http://subdominio.site.com/uma_coisa_qualquer.keykey"></a>
<a href="https://subdominio.site.com/outra_coisa_qualquer.key"></a>
<a href="https://subdominio.site.com/outra_coisa_qualquer.keys"></a>';

preg_match_all('/\"((http|https)\:\/\/([^\"]+)\.key)\"/', $conteudo_da_pagina, $ocorrencias);

print_r($ocorrencias[1]);

/*
Array
(
    [0] => http://site.com/palavra.key
    [1] => https://site.com/palavra.key
    [2] => http://subdominio.site.com/palavra.key
    [3] => https://subdominio.site.com/outra_coisa_qualquer.key
)
*********************************************************************/
```

**@edit** (conforme edição da pergunta):

```
<?php

// $texto_da_busca = file_get_contents('...');
$texto_da_busca = '#EXTINF:-1 tvg-logo="http://www.brandemia.org/sites/default/files/sites/default/files/axn_logo_antiguo.jpg" group-title="Cine",AXN (MX)
http://live.izzitv.mx/Content/HLS/Live/Channel(AXN)/index.key

#EXTINF:-1 tvg-logo="https://i.imgur.com/Wrgs4X2.png" group-title="Cine",AMC (MX)
http://live.izzitv.mx/Content/HLS/Live/Channel(AMC_HD)/index.key';

preg_match_all('/((http|https)\:\/\/(.*?)\.key)/', $texto_da_busca, $matches);

print_r($matches[1]);
/* Retorna:
Array
(
    [0] => http://live.izzitv.mx/Content/HLS/Live/Channel(AXN)/index.key
    [1] => http://live.izzitv.mx/Content/HLS/Live/Channel(AMC_HD)/index.key
)
***************************************************************************/
```

Comment: LiPe  o site que faço a consulta, ele exibi um arquivo de texto, porem nao tenho acesso a esse arquivo, e nesse aequivo os links, não são exibidos dentro de href"" ,são soltos praticamente e teria que achar eles sem atributos, isso é possível ?

Comment: Lipe esse código funcionou para uma situação, porém ele está me retornando uma lista com todas as urls, haveria como fazer uma modificação para apenas exibir um por vez apenas ???, apareçe assim Array ( [0] => link 1, [1] => link 2